# Tools similar to "Ruby Sadist" tools (Flog, Flay, Heckle) for PHP

Tags: php, ruby, unit-testing, code-analysis

I just heard about the "Ruby sadist" tools for ruby development that analyze ABC complexity and your unit test quality. Flog, Flay, Heckle - they are called. More on them: http://ruby.sadi.st/Ruby_Sadist.html

Are there any tools like that for PHP development? I'm espacially interested in a tool that scans PHP unit tests for quality, but any recomendations on code complexity analyzers will be appreciated and rewarded.

Thank you :)

Comment: Related blog post: https://chrsm.org/post/static-analysis-tools-for-php/

Comment: Not the best place for this, but you can look at Sonar PHP support (http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PHP+Plugin) either to use it or as an inspiration. Options I know off are  PHPDepend, PHPCodeSniffer, PHPMD